# Zend_Navigation - navigation menu generate inappropriate navigation links

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

i am having problem using `Zend_Navigation` here is my `navigation.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>
    <admin>
        <dashboard>
            <label>Dashboard</label>
            <module>admin</module>
            <controller>dashboard</controller>
            <action>index</action>
        </dashboard>
    </admin>
</configdata>
```

here is my bootsrapping method.

```
public function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/navigation.xml', 'admin');
    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    $view->navigation($navigation);
}
```

and my admin layout `admin.phtml` contains

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu(); ?>
```

the problem is the navigation menu dashboard changes accordingly with the current `module/controller/action`

for instance.

```
if:
current page: admin/dashboard/index
generates `<a href="/admin/dashboard">Dashboard</a>`

if:
current page: admin/item/index
generates `<a href="/admin/item">Dashboard</a>`
```

whereas for second i expect the url not to change. the second method should generate

```
current page: admin/item/index
generates `<a href="/admin/dashboard">Dashboard</a>`
```

what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have multiple routes defined? if so, add a `<route>` key to your `<dashboard>` section of the navigation.xml file that has the correct route name.

Comment: Yes I do have multiple route defined, let me check with your solution

Comment: Excellent. You'll also need to do the same if you use the `url()` view  helper. The second parameter is the route to use.